# The terraform init command is failing in my .tf file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

### The terraform code of file - "myec2.tf"

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "eu-west-1"
  access_key = "<<access key id>>"
  secret_key = "<<secret key id>>"
}

# chosen from the RESOURCE section in Terraform 'Provider' section
resource "aws_instance" "terra_ec2" {
    ami = "ami-07d9160fa81ccffb5"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    provider = "https://registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"
}
```

### The ERROR MESSAGES obtained after issuing the "terraform init" command

```
There are some problems with the configuration, described below.

The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.

Warning: Quoted references are deprecated

  on first_ec2.tf line 11, in resource "aws_instance" "terra_ec2":
  11:     provider = "https://registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"

In this context, references are expected literally rather than in quotes.
Terraform 0.11 and earlier required quotes, but quoted references are now
deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Terraform. Remove the
quotes surrounding this reference to silence this warning.


Error: Invalid character

  on first_ec2.tf line 11, in resource "aws_instance" "terra_ec2":
  11:     provider = "https://registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"
```

Expected an attribute access or an index operator.

Comment: This time I get this when I remove the "provider" from the "resource" block:  Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/aws...

Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws:
could not connect to registry.terraform.io: Failed to request discovery
document: Get "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json": read
tcp <<ip_address_1>>:51717-><<ip_address_2>>:443: wsarecv: An existing connection was
forcibly closed by the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

You already set the `provider` in your terraform code.

You do not need the provider key in your resource.

Remove the provider:

```
resource "aws_instance" "terra_ec2" {
    ami = "ami-07d9160fa81ccffb5"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

Comment: Used "terraform-provider-aws_v3.5.0_x5.exe" with "terraform_0.12.0_windows_amd64". The "terraform init" command worked fine but the "terraform plan" commnd gives the error - Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post "https://sts.amazonaws.com/": read tcp <<ip_address_1>>:56837-><<ip_address_2>>:443: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Comment: I went through https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/9869 but couldn't understand it properly. I don't know if the FIX is there.

Comment: It looks like you need to set up the account you’re using for terraform, to access AWS, with the correct roles/policies

Comment: Is the article https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/9869 good enough? Please refer some links too

Comment: terraform validate - also works fine. The issue is only the above error in "terraform plan" command

Comment: Your issue is not with terraform, it’s with your credentials. The error is stating that the AWS provider could not validate your provider credentials. Can you make sure your AWS Keys and AWS region are the correct ones you’re trying to connect with? Terraform plan attempts to make a connection to the AWS resource using your credentials you placed in your provider. That would be something I would double check first.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I shall generate the credentials again and update you.

Comment: I logged into the AWS Console with IAM User "sudip_terraform". I am at the Region "eu-west-1" but still getting the same error. In the ".tf file", I have pasted the ACCESS KEY and SECRET KEY of the IAM User "sudip_terraform". Still the same problem persists. Kindly advise.

Comment: And does the role have an assumerole to manage ec2 resources?

Comment: Opened a new thread here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63759651/error-the-role-arnawsiammy-aws-account-numberrole-sudip-terraform-ec2